# Как отрендерить html документ в Spring

Tags: java, spring

Есть код:

```
package com.example.here.controller;

import com.example.here.entity.User;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

@Controller
public class MainController {
    @GetMapping("/")
    public String main(Model model) {
        return "main";
    }
}
```

main.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>You are in main page</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

В гайде из ютуба при переходе на localhost:8080 рендериться main.html, но почему-то этого не произошло. main.html находится в resources/templates/main.html

Вместо рендеринга выдаётся ошибка:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: может не указано что нужно брать из templates? Напр. настрока в spring `spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/` или не прописан путь в `ClassLoaderTemplateResolver` .

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что в том гайде в зависимостях был добавлен thymeleaf.
В maven это делается добавлением в файл pom.xml

```
<dependencies>
 <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
  <version>3.2.3</version>
 </dependency>
</dependencies>
```